# Outlook 2007 giving outgoing PDF attachment new generic name and saving it to temp folder

Tags: email, pdf, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a single user who is suddenly experiencing Outlook 2007 changing the name of a selected PDF attachment and saving the renamed attachment to her secure temp folder. Any ideas why this is occurring?

OS is Win7

The PDF in question came from a Word document and is stored on a NAS drive in our network.

I have examined the temp folder and it only holds a small number of PDF attachments but only 1 with the generic "coded" name.

Each time we attach the same Word-created PDF document to an email it will appear in the list with the same "coded" name with an increasing number at the end of the name and be re-saved in the temp folder.

We then saved the PDF from Word to a new folder on the C Drive and did not encounter the same name-change.

Any ideas why this would be occurring? Is there a setting in Outlook or Windows which has been triggered to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007 is getting quite old at this point.

Try two repairs:

(1) Uninstall, restart and re-install Outlook 2007.

(2) Delete the Outlook Profile for the user. Restart the computer and make a new Outlook Profile for this user for this Outlook Account. (Outlook Profiles are in Control Panel / Mail)

It may be worth upgrading to a newer version of Office.